# What is the ConsoleAppender.setWriter equivalent in log4j-2

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to migrate from log4j-1.2 to log4j-2

What is the equivalent for the following lines in log4j-2?

```java
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;

public static final Logger s_logger = Logger.getLogger(x.class);
ConsoleAppender ca = new ConsoleAppender();
ca.setWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8"));
ca.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%-5p [%t]: %m%n"));
s_logger.addAppender(ca);
```

I wasn't been able to find the answer in Apache documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Log4j2 there are two main changes concerning your code:

- Log4j2 is split into an API and an implementation, therefore an `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` is not necessarily an `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger`,
- components are created using the builder pattern and don't have setters.

The closest equivalent of your code uses a [`WriterAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/WriterAppender.html):

```java
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
if (logger instanceof org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) {
    StringLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withPattern("%-5p [%t]: %m%n").build();
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Appender appender = WriterAppender.newBuilder().setTarget(writer).setLayout(layout).build();
    ((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) logger).addAppender(appender);
}
```

The [`ConsoleAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/ConsoleAppender.html) is restricted to using either `System.out` or `System.err` and uses the default system encoding:

```java
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
if (logger instanceof org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) {
    StringLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withPattern("%-5p [%t]: %m%n").build();
    Appender appender = ConsoleAppender.newBuilder().setTarget(Target.SYSTEM_OUT).setLayout(layout).build();
    ((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) logger).addAppender(appender);
}
```

The code samples above use these imports:

```java
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.StringLayout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.Target;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.WriterAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;
```